# WPBakery replacing image URLs in shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, wpbakery

I have a wordpress site migrated to azure recently, I have transferred all the media to azure blob storage and changed URLs in the database. I am using WPBakery Page Builder plugin to build the site. When I add an image it adds something like `[vc_single_image image=\"25436\"]` in post content. The short code loads image (path of image is) from media library. I want to change the path of the image so that it loads from azure blob storage. How can I edit the shortcode?

Comment: Check if the shortcode implementation executes any hooks that allow you to modify the result; if not, you might need to remove the existing shortcode implementation completely (`remove_shortcode`), and then add your own with modified functionality …